# Deploying assembly normally in the GAC with my project?

Tags: c#, deployment, assemblies, gac, j#

I built a web application that uses the J# libraries which works fine in my cpu, however, when I deploy it to my shared server. I get an error message: Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'vjslib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

So basically, the server doesn't have visual j# installed. The problem is they wont install it because it is a shared server.

Is there a way I can deploy the J# assemblies with my project so that it will work on the shared server without it being registered in the GAC?

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution: Try to copy the assemblies your application needs into the same folder where your application resides.

The following MSDN article explains [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf.aspx).

Also, you may find more options (including copying all J# related dlls into a subfolder of the application folder if needed) in the following link when the runtime cannot find the assembly in the GAC: [Locating the Assembly through Codebases or Probing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15hyw9x3.aspx)

Comment: And all that should be needed is to click on the offending assembly in the Solution Explorer under References, and set the "Copy to Local" property to true, the assembly will be copied to the directory of your .exe output, and you can just collect and deploy those.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about J# I can only suggest that you try just distributing the required libraries along with your program (place them in the same directory), I believe if it can't find the library in the GAC it will revert to look in the current directory.